# How to substitute variables in lists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

How can you write a predicate in Prolog, which takes 3 lists, `L1` is a list that contains constants and variables, `L2` contains constants, and `L3` is a some list. The predicate should return true iff the variables of the first list substituted with the corresponding element of the second list equals the third list.

Like if `L1_i` is a variable, it needs to be substituted with `L2_i`, and then if it needs to be equal to `L3_i`.

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Unification (i.e. `=/2`) does that, actually.

```
?- [X, a, Y, b, Z] = [1, A, 2, B, 3].
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = 3,
A = a,
B = b.
```

Oh, but you need three lists:

```
?- [X,a,Y,b,Z] = [1,A,2,B,3], [1,A,2,B,3] = [1,a,2,b,3].
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = 3,
A = a,
B = b.
```

Sorry, let's make it look more like your assignment:

```
?- L1 = [X,a,Y,b,Z], L2 = [1,A,2,B,3], L3 = [1,a,2,b,3], L1 = L2, L2 = L3.
L1 = [1, a, 2, b, 3],
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = 3,
L2 = [1, a, 2, b, 3],
A = a,
B = b,
L3 = [1, a, 2, b, 3].
```

:)

Comment: I read the assignment in a more restricted way. It seems that equality should be enforced only on 'variables slots', and not on entire lists.